# A more elegant way to get a percentage?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am at a very basic level in math and am looking for a more compact way to get, say, 75% of something.

```
(num/4)*3
```

Is there any smarter way to the same goal?

Comment: Perhaps you'd prefer (num*3)/4 or num*0.75.

Comment: (num*3)/4 or (num*3)/4.0 should have the least rounding problems, I think. Or maybe num-num/4.0.

Answer (score 4):

In general, if you want to find $p\%$ of a number $x$, we compute $$\dfrac{p}{100} \times x$$

In your case, $$75\% \times x \;= \;\dfrac{75}{100}\times x\; = \;0.75 x \;= \;\dfrac34 x$$

There really is no method more elegant than this.